# Jquery Mobile Scrollview & google maps route

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, jquery-mobile, scrollview

I'm not sure if I am implementing the scroll view incorrectly, or if the plugin just doesn't like the content created by google maps. But on my route page I am not seeing any signs of the plugin working. I did my best to follow the examples on github I don't think I am missing any of the javascript files. A side question, just for clarification do you need both `data-scroll="true"` and `data-scroll="y"` for vertical scrolling, or does the `data-scroll="y"` turn on the scrolling on its own?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not the answer but it's to long as a comment

Well just running the site in Chrome I get these errors:

- jquery.easing.1.3.js:6  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
- jquery.mobile.scrollview.js:6   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
- scrollview.js:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
- directionstest.cfm:38   Uncaught ReferenceError: settimeout is not defined
- directionstest.cfm:88   Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined

Well just running the site on the iPhone I get these errors:

- jquery.easing.1.3.js:6  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
- jquery.mobile.scrollview.js:6   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
- scrollview.js:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
- directionstest.cfm:38   Uncaught ReferenceError: settimeout is not defined

[How to turn on the debug console in Mobile Safari (iOS)](http://maisonbisson.com/blog/post/14447/step-by-step-turn-on-the-iphone-ipads-web-debugging-console/)

Comment: Congratulations. It's your 100th answer in jquery-mobile tag!

Answer (score 0):

If you set `data-scroll="y"` it should work (I haven't ever gotten `data-scroll='true'` to do anything).

I would also set it on the content, not on the `"#body"` div. If you put it on the body div, the scroll bar would be inside that. (Maybe just personal preference, but it feels weird to have the scroll bar inside that.)

**EDIT**: Chromium debugger says Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined